# How to remove a flutter emulator

Tags: flutter

Running `flutter emulators --create --name apple_ios_simulator` will create a duplicate emulator named `apple_ios_simulator` but set the device type to a Pixel by default. Now if you run `flutter emulators --launch apple_ios_simulator` a Google Pixel emulator is launched.

Is there CRUD options for individual flutter emulators or a way to revert to the default set of emulators?

Answer (score 2):

**Using [Android Virtual Device Manager](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds) to delete Android emulators**

Open the Android Studio, click on Tools -> ADV Manager.

A new screen will open with a list of your Android emulators, just click on the arrow in "Action" column and then "delete".

I know is not a complete answer but i hope it can help you to delete at least the Android emulators from your `flutter emulators` list.

Answer (score 0):

In android use 
Run emulator: 
emulador -avd [NAME DEVICE]

List emulator
avdmanager -v list

Delate emulator
avdmanager -v delete avd -n [NAME EMULATOR]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "In android"?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
avdmanager list avd
avdmanager delete avd -n flutter_emulator
```

---

How did I found this?

- `android` → depricated
- `avdmanager -h` → show help
- `avdmanager delete -h` → show help

```
Valid actions are composed of a verb and an optional direct object:
-   list              : Lists existing targets or virtual devices.
-   list avd          : Lists existing Android Virtual Devices.
-   list target       : Lists existing targets.
-   list device       : Lists existing devices.
- create avd          : Creates a new Android Virtual Device.
-   move avd          : Moves or renames an Android Virtual Device.
- delete avd          : Deletes an Android Virtual Device.
```

```
Action "delete avd":
  Deletes an Android Virtual Device.
Options:
  -n --name    : Name of the AVD to delete. [required]
```